# Radial Coordinate or Equivalence Principle: What Determines Time Dilation in Free Fall?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, equivalence-principle

I have a question regarding the math of General Relativity. Let's consider an observer with two clocks attached to their head and feet. If the person is in free fall, their feet would have a lower radial coordinate than their head. According to the calculation of the Schwarzschild metric, the clock at their head would still run faster than the clock at their feet. However, in view of Einstein's famous equivalence principle, a free-fall observer on Earth is an inertial reference frame, similar to being in empty space. Therefore, two clocks attached to their head and feet should tick at the same rate when the observer is in free fall, and only tick at different rates when there is a normal force on the ground causing the observer to accelerate.

Sabine's recent video about Relativity pointed out that for a rocket man to experience time dilation near a black hole, they would have to accelerate their rocket to maintain the radial coordinate. It is this acceleration that causes time dilation, not spacetime curvature near a black hole. I find this to be contradictory to the math of the Schwarzschild metric, since Rocket man can maintain their radial coordinate while orbiting the black hole, which is a free-fall path.

The question is, should I trust the metric or the condition given based on the equivalence principle, assuming the free-falling body is small enough so the tidal forces could be ignored?
In other words, the radial coordinate is what matters, or the condition given by the equivalence principle is that the person must feel a normal force from the ground that matters?

Note: If anyone cannot answer this question, please don't downvote it so that those who are more knowledgeable can answer it. Thank you!

Comment: Deleting a question that is not well received and reposting is not an acceptable strategy on SE. You are likely going to see your question being closed.

Comment: Blaming the asker for lack of knowledge is unprofessional. While you were incorrect about the tidal force, as an expert, you could have answered my question.

Comment: The cause of time dilation in the equivalence principle is the effect of the normal force on the observer, and it is the gravitational potential, not the strength of the gravitational field, that matters between two locations.

Comment: I didn't blame you. I simply told you what the rules are on SE and that not following them may have consequences. Take care.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalence principle is a useful guide, but it's not the final word on anything. In physics, always, the math is the final word. If the metric says the head and feet have different times, then they do -- and in fact that is what happens in the real world. For example, GPS clocks are in free fall but they have to be adjusted for their height above the Earth (their gravitational potential).

Sabine's video on relativity had some confusing and perhaps a bit misleading sections, and this was one of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance! Your answer was exactly what I needed.